# The following code is allowing me to authenticate in firebase authentication. But do not "users" store firestore databse

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

The Following code helped is working by storing the user in authentication but it is not storing the user details in firestore database. Please help me fix the code so that it stores in firestore-database. I tried the firestore links and many youtube videos. But I'm unable to fix. Please help me fix this issue

```
export default function Register(props) {
  const [firstname, setfirstname] = useState('');
  const [lastname,setlastname] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [phonenumber, setphonenumber] = useState('');
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

    const onSignup = () => {
        if (firstname.length == 0 || lastname.length==0 || email.length == 0 || password.length == 0) {
            setIsValid({ bool: true, boolSnack: true, message: "Please fill out everything" })
            return;
        }
        if (password.length < 6) {
            setIsValid({ bool: true, boolSnack: true, message: "passwords must be at least 6 characters" })
            return;
        }
        if (password.length < 6) {
            setIsValid({ bool: true, boolSnack: true, message: "passwords must be at least 6 characters" })
            return;
        }
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {

                if (!snapshot.exist) {
                    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .then(() => {
                            if (snapshot.exist) {
                                return
                            }
                            firebase.firestore().collection("users")
                                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                                .set({
                                  email,
                                  emailVerified: false,
                                  firstname,
                                  lastname,
                                  phonenumber,
                                  disabled: false

                                })
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            setIsValid({ bool: true, boolSnack: true, message: "Something went wrong" })
                        })
                }
            }).catch(() => {
                setIsValid({ bool: true, boolSnack: true, message: "Something went wrong1" })
            })

    }
```

I'm expecting to fix the code and store the user values in the firestore database

Answer (score 0):

Get the user uid from the firebase auth return, try this:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((user) => {
                firebase.firestore()
                    .collection('users').doc(user.user.uid)
                    .set({
                        //set all the data you want here
                    }).then(() => {
                        // added data to firestore and registered successfully
                    }).catch(() => {
                        //failed to add data to firestore
                    })

            }).catch(() => {
                // failed to create new account
            })
```

Comment: It didnt work for me .